# Gatling - Check multiple values with JsonPath

Tags: scala, testing, gatling

I am using Gatling 2.1.7 and I cant't find a way to check multiple values with JsonPath.

Lets pretend I have this Json:

```
{
  "messageTyp": "wsopen",
  "userId": "1" 
}
```

I do need to check both values.
It is easy to check on of the values:

```
.check(wsAwait.within(2).expect(1).jsonPath("$..messageType").is("wsopen"))
```

But because this tests are running in a "feeder"-loop, there are a lot "wsopen" messages, coming back asynchronous. I need to check, that every user receives exactly one "wsopen" message.

I need something like

```
.check(wsAwait.within(2).expect(1).jsonPath("$..messageType").is("wsopen").and.jsonPath("$..userId").is("${userid}")) // won't compile
```

Anybody a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) directly:

```
jsonPath("$[?(@.messageTyp=='wsopen' && @.userId=='1')]").exists
```